# Thermal conductivity affected by electrical current

Tags: electricity, material-science, thermal-conductivity

Does anyone know of any materials whereby the thermal conductivity can be changed by passing an electrical current through the material?

Answer (score 3):

Materials that become superconductors have different thermal conductivities in the normal and the superconducting state. When in the superconducting state, starting a current larger than the critical one will drive such a material to its normal state, thereby altering its thermal conductivity.